# Why is converting my database to UTF-8 truncating entries?

Tags: database, mysql, characters

I'm running WordPress 4.1.1. My site is hosted at NearlyFreeSpeech.

I've been using my WordPress blog since the days when it encoded information in the `latin1` charset. This week, I realized that certain posts on my blog (like these: [1](http://spencerdub.me/blog/2011/09/allons-y/)-[2](http://spencerdub.me/blog/2011/09/end-of-orientation/)-[3](http://spencerdub.me/blog/2012/01/reflections-on-a-semester-in-japan/)) weren't displaying Japanese characters--the characters either show up as question marks, or as strings of characters like æ—¥æœ¬èªž.

Clearly, this is an encoding error. Looking at my database in phpMyAdmin, I have many tables and columns in my database with their collation set to `latin1_swedish_ci`. I sought to fix this by changing the database to UTF-8 in a variety of different ways. They all had the exact same result.

The ways I tried to change the database encoding to UTF-8:

1. Use the [UTF-8 Database Converter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/utf-8-database-converter/) plugin
2. Follow [this guide](http://blogsuccessjournal.com/blog-tips-and-advice/wordpress-tips/seeing-weird-characters-on-blog-how-to-fix-wordpress-character-encoding-latin1-to-utf8/) to export the database, replace all instances of "latin1" with "UTF8"
3. Use a SQL script to convert tables and columns to blob, and then to UTF-8 text (detailed [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets#Converting_columns_to_blob.2C_then_back_to_original_format_with_new_charset))
4. Use a SQL script to *recast* tables and columns to the datatype they contain, then to blob, and then to UTF-8 text (detailed [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets#Variant:_3-step_conversion_when_data_and_table_charset_already_don.27t_match))

**Expected results:**

My site appears the same as it was above, with all themes and settings intact, but now displaying Japanese characters properly.

**Actual results for *all* of the above methods:**

Japanese still doesn't display correctly. What's more, database entries end abruptly; for instance, some entries in `post_content` are missing some or most of their original content. Custom shortcodes, defined by the Shortcoder plugin and stored in the `shortcoder_data` row in `wp_options`, are broken because the `shortcoder_data` entry got abruptly truncated. My theme options, including custom CSS and fonts, appear to have been reset or damaged, most likely due to similar abrupt truncation of database entries.

Luckily, I had the foresight to make all these changes on a duplicate database, so I have a backup with all my data intact.

When I compare the altered data in `post_content` to the original, I notice something: nearly all of the truncated strings begin with a special character. For instance, a post that once read:

> Today it was a pleasant 72° and sunny.

will, in the altered database, read:

> Today it was a pleasant 72

I haven't gone through and found *all* of my truncated posts--I know nothing about mySQL, so I'd have to do that by hand, and that would be an exercise in patience. However, out of a sample of 8 posts that got truncated, 6 of them were clearly truncated at a special character.

What do I need to do to properly convert my database so that Japanese characters display correctly without causing this data loss--or, barring a complete solution, what can I do to properly diagnose what's going on?

Thank you.

**Update: Extra information**

A few more things.

I used to have a lot of posts on my blog that displayed strings like *Iâ€™m* instead of *I’m*, *naÃ¯ve* instead of *naïve*. Like I mentioned above, Japanese was displaying as long strings like æ—¥æœ¬èªž instead of 日本語. I went through and replaced these strings where I saw them, replacing Ã¯ with a proper ï (for instance).

I didn't catch all of them, however, and there are a few posts in my database that still have *naÃ¯ve* instead of *naïve*.

When I look at those posts on the databases I've altered... they display *correctly*. They don't truncate. All of the garbled characters have seamlessly translated into their "proper" equivalents. Even the Japanese converted.

In the posts where I went back and "corrected" the garbled characters, however, where I have *naïve* and not *naÃ¯ve*, the content in the database gets truncated on import as described above.

Comment: Do you have shell access to your server?

Comment: Export the database in phpMyAdmin using the extra options area to ensure the file is exported as utf-8, then search within the downloaded .sql file for a known truncated post to make sure the posts aren't actually truncated in the dump.  After that create a new utf-8 database, import the dump and change the details over in wp-config.php

Comment: Thanks, @JasonMurray. I do have shell access. I tried what you suggested, and the posts aren't truncated in the dump. Upon trying to import the database, I got an error with regards to a line that read `/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;`. The error read, "#1231 - Variable 'character_set_client' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'".

Comment: Can you follow the same process but instead of save output to file select view output as text, then select all of the output and copy paste it into the SQL tab on your clean new UTF-8 database and execute it.

Comment: @JasonMurray: 5 minutes after executing the 20,000-line SQL script, I got a timeout error: "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded".

Comment: @JasonMurray Update: phpMyAdmin had created the tables up until it timed out, so I just copied the query from the last successful table import onward and executed that. I got this error message, though: "#1062 - Duplicate entry '18' for key 'PRIMARY'"; in reference to: `--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table \`wp_catt_visibility\`
--
ALTER TABLE \`wp_catt_visibility\`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (\`catt_ID\`);".`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21531/discussion-between-spencerdub-and-jason-murray).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was one of mixed encoding. Some fields contained data encoded properly as UTF-8; others contained data encoded as something else, probably ISO-8859-1. When imported to a new UTF-8 database, this was causing truncation.

### My steps to solve this:

1. Copy the original database, `wordpress`, to a new database, `wordpress2`. Make sure the collation of `wordpress2` is set to UTF-8.
2. Follow any one of the steps above to convert the tables and columns of `wordpress2` to UTF-8. This will cause truncation.
3. For each row on `wordpress` containing entries where the data when converted to UTF-8 was not the same as the data when converted to ASCII, update the corresponding row in `wordpress2` with the `wordpress` data, converted to UTF-8. A sample script is below.

### The script:

```
UPDATE wordpress3.wp_options wp3
INNER JOIN wordpress.wp_options wp ON (wp.option_id = wp3.option_id 
    AND convert(wp.option_value using utf8) != convert(wp.option_value using ascii))
SET wp3.option_value = convert(wp.option_value using utf8);
```

A more knowledgeable friend wrote a series of scripts for me that queried `information_schema` to locate all the columns containing entries where `convert(value using utf8) != convert(value using ascii)`, and to then generate versions of the script above for them.

### Results:

It worked! On my new database, I can save Japanese without it turning into question marks (because the character set has successfully been set to UTF-8), and all the mis-encoded fields that were causing data truncation have been fixed.

There are some posts that contain misencoded characters, but since I can find almost all of those strings by searching for â, Ã, Â, or æ, I can just go in and manually replace them.